# Creating virtual host in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: virtualhost, laravel-5.6, ubuntu-18.04

I m trying to create virtual host in my **ubuntu 18.04** for my laravel project and i had installed xampp as well but there is no any apache2 folder created in my **/etc** folder so that i cant find **sites-available**/ folder 
How to create virtual host in that case?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this link and follow the given simple steps :

[How To Configure Apache Virtual Hosts In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-part-1/)

If ant any point you find any difficulty please let me know, I will try my level best to provide solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll have to install a Lamp Stack. You can follow [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/lamp/install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-18-04/) guide for it.

Then you can use [this other](https://blog.e-zest.com/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-host-configuration-on-lamp-environment/) guide to set up an Apache Virtual Host.

Note: You don't need Xampp at all.